# How to use Handles.Label to draw text in Scene view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can use Debug.DrawLine to draw lines between objects.
but now i want above/on each waypoint to draw/write a number.
So in the scene view I will see 1,2,3,4...on each waypoint.

I tried to add DrawGizmo but not sure how to use it in the Update function and I'm getting some warnings with the gizmo:

The first warnings is to remove each UnityEditor to make it simplify:
So I removed all the places with UnityEditor. Then I'm get warning:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning   CS0618  'GizmoType.SelectedOrChild' is obsolete: 'Use
>   InSelectionHierarchy instead (UnityUpgradable) ->
>   InSelectionHierarchy'

So not sure how to use this Gizmo at all.

```
void Update()
    {
        if (MyCommands.walkbetweenwaypoints == true)
        {
            WayPointsAI();
        }
        // create lines between each checkpoint //
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(waypoints[i].transform.position, waypoints[i + 1].transform.position, Color.blue);

        }

        // create line between original transform start position 
        // and the current transform position //
        Debug.DrawLine(originalPosition, transform.position, Color.red);

        // create a line between current transform position and the next waypoint target
        // each time reached a waypoint.
        Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, myTransform.position, Color.green);
    }

    [UnityEditor.DrawGizmo(GizmoType.SelectedOrChild | UnityEditor.GizmoType.NotSelected)]
    static void DrawGameObjectName(Transform transform, UnityEditor.GizmoType gizmoType)
    {
        Handles.Label(transform.position, transform.gameObject.name);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Handles.Label` is tricky.

Let's say that your script name is called `WayPointScript`. Below is what it should look like:

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class WayPointScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] waypoints;

    void Update()
    {
        if (MyCommands.walkbetweenwaypoints == true)
        {
            WayPointsAI();
        }
        // create lines between each checkpoint //
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(waypoints[i].transform.position, waypoints[i + 1].transform.position, Color.blue);

        }

        // create line between original transform start position 
        // and the current transform position //
        Debug.DrawLine(originalPosition, transform.position, Color.red);

        // create a line between current transform position and the next waypoint target
        // each time reached a waypoint.
        Debug.DrawLine(target.transform.position, myTransform.position, Color.green);
    }
}
```

Noticed the `[ExecuteInEditMode]` on top of it? That **must** be there.

Now, you can use the code below to draw the `Text` with `Handles.Label`.

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(WayPointScript))]
public class TextDrawer : Editor
{

    void OnSceneGUI()
    {

        Debug.Log("Running");
        WayPointScript t = target as WayPointScript;

        //Create Text on each checkpoint //
        for (int i = 0; i < t.waypoints.Length; i++)
        {
            UnityEditor.Handles.Label(t.waypoints[i].transform.position, (i + 1).ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

You want the texts to be on top? Add offset to the y-axis of the `t.waypoints[i].transform.position` variable.